# Solving the linear recurrence $ f(n) = f(n - 1) + 12f(n-2)$

Tags: recurrence-relations, solution-verification

> Solve the linear recurrence: 
>   $$ f(1) = 10, f(2) = -2,\quad f(n) = f(n - 1) + 12f(n-2)$$

My solution is below.

**Assume:**
$f(n) = x^n$

$$x^n = x^{n-1} + 12x^{n-2}$$
$$x^2 = x + 12  $$
$$x^2 - x - 12 = 0$$

*Using the quadratic formula:*

$$x_1 = 4 ,\quad x_2 = -3$$

*Solution form:*

c -> Unknown constant 
$$f(n) = c_1(4)^n + c2(-3)^n$$

$$10 = c_1 + c_2$$
$$-2 = 4(c_1) - 3(c2)$$

$$c_1 = 4, c_2 = 6$$

*Closed form:*

$$f(n) = 4(4)^n + 6(-3)^n$$

I'm not sure if did this correctly, but I'm having trouble with the last part with proving both the recurrence and closed form.

Comment: Problem setting up the equations for $c_1$ and $c_2$. The equations should have been $f(1)=4c_1-3c_2=10$, $16c_1+9c_2=-2$.  You would have been right if the numbers given were $f(0)$ and $f(1)$.

Comment: Oh!! I see, Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Minor slip, you probably got used to have initial conditions $f(0)=\dots$, $f(1)=\dots$.

Comment: I don't now what you mean by proving the recurrence and the closed form. You can indeed show that the answer you got satisfies the recurrence, by calculating $f(n)$, $f(n-1)$, $f(n-2)$ and verifying by algebraic manipulation that indeed $f(n)=f(n-1)+12f(n-2)$. Unless you were explicitly asked to do so, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Oh, I thought I had to because I had to do it before. Thank you for clarifying this for me! :D

Comment: @Andre,  well, that's one way of verifying his answer (in an exam, I'd do it), most of the times it's faster than checking every calculation. Also, you should turn your comments into an answer, as you solved all of OP's doubts.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: Done. Probably in an exam checking that $f(1)$, $f(2)$, $f(3)$, and perhaps $f(4)$ are right would be enough to give one a feeling of security.

Answer (score 1):

There was a minor slip in finding the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$. The initial conditions are $f(1)=10$ and $f(2)=-2$, so the linear equations we get are $4c_1-3c_2=10$, $16c_1+9c_2=-2$. Solving, we get $c_1=1$ and $c_2=-2$.

**Remark:** You have found a closed form. Unless you are specifically asked, there is no need to *prove* that the closed form is correct. But if you wish to do so, it is easy to check by plugging in that $4^n -2(-3)^n$ is what it ought to be at $n=1$ and $n=2$.  And we can verify by substitution that if $a_n=4^n-2(-3)^n$ then $a_n=a_{n-1}+12a_{n-2}$. The functions $f(n)$ and $a_n$ satisfy the same initial conditions, and the same recurrence, so (in principle by induction) they are equal at all positive integers.